# Python OpenCV: Reading an image along x and y axis

Tags: python, image, opencv

**Aim:** I am trying to read the first point (non-zero) here in this image (shown as the red arrow)

[image]

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

import cv2
im1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Desktop/Line.png', 0)
for x in range(0, im1.shape[0], 1):
    for y in range(0, im1.shape[1], 1):
        cpt = im1[x][y]
        if 0 < cpt <= 255 :
           print("This is the value", x,y)
```

But, the point being printed is this (a zero point):

[image]

How is this so?

The **original** image:

[image]

Comment: Post a clean source image please.And you method is ineffecient.

Comment: I have added the source image here.

Comment: With your code i get (91, 387) what are you getting? BTW, even though your code may be correct, x is actually the row and y is the col... in cartesian coordinates it will be (91, 387) but as you are printing it is the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is clean(without noise), then try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("JKNp9.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ys,xs = np.nonzero(gray)
idx = np.argsort(xs)[0]

pt = xs[idx], ys[idx]

print(pt)
cv2.line(img, pt, pt, (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

The pt is: `(27, 388)`

This's it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix, could you please kindly tell me why my code doesn't work? :/ I am unable to find any error in the logic. :/

Comment: @Jeremy Your code scan the image in row mode, while the first non-zero point `(x,y)` should be `(91, 387)`. You draw the wrong code. And you should scan in col mode to get the left most point.